# MySQLi database tables to JSON - need template

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, mysqli

I saw a lot of examples on the net to how to extract a DB query result into JSON, but none of them really worked.

I need a PHP template of a few lines that will retrieve a table and convert it to JSON, echoing back to the client a string of JSON that I can parse on the client side.

I need to use this template for a get request using JavaScript XHR.
Since I'm mostly programing client side, I'm running into some difficulties building this script.
I would appreciate your help and will learn greatly from it :)

Comment: Unless you post your efforts hence not simply asking someone to do the work for you, you'll most likely get negative ratings... and the negative votes have started already

Comment: 1) run query 2) fetch results 3) build php data structure with results 4) run structure through json_encode 5) output json somewhere 6) ??? 7) profit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any Database connection you like. MySQLi, in this case, [adapted from this example](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php):

```
$mysqli->real_query("SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY id ASC");
$res = $mysqli->use_result();

$orders = array();

while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $orders[$row['id']] = $row;
}
```

And simply use `json_encode` to generate a JSON string:

```
$json_string = json_encode($orders);
```

Shouldn't be much more difficult than that.